# Redirecting using php doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a page in which the user can fill in his email adress. When the user clicks on 'Send', a .php script is called. In this script, a POST is made to an external webservice and an answer is received containing an URL. The .php then navigates to that URL.

It looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Email</title>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/customtheme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <a class="ui-btn-left" href="index.html" data-icon="back">Back</a>
        <h1><span></span></h1>
        <a class="ui-btn-right" href="#" data-icon="info">i & &euro;</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" data-position="relative">
        <div class="inform">
            <form method="POST" class="thedataform" position:relative action="send.php" >
                <span>Email adress:</span>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></input>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" style="width:100%" name="smsbutton" value="Send" >
                </div>
            </form
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And send.php looks like this:

```
<?php
    $xml = file_get_contents('xml.xml');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://other.webservice/yyy/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

    $sXML = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $oXML = simplexml_load_string($sXML);
    $url = (string) $oXML->RETURNEDURL;

    if (isset($_POST["email"]))
    {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    }
    else
    {
        $email = null;
    }

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    setcookie("email", $email);
    header('Location: '.$url);
    exit;
?>
```

Now, everything works fine when I navigate to send.php directly. I get redirected to the other website (the RETURNEDURL).

But when I want to run the .php using the submit button, stuff goes wrong. Since I'm using JQuery and JQuery Mobile, I get the message "Error Loading Page". The following message pops up in my FireBug:

> [12:53:31.097] POST http://myserver.com/send.php
>   [HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily 1456ms]

When I comment out one of the following two lines:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

The redirect works but my page gets messed up ugly. Is it possible the error occurs because I'm going from an HTTP to a HTTPS post? What is the problem here?

Comment: jQuery mobile uses a single page. Any requests which are made must be done via AJAX, and handled within that page.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan How can I best approach that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my website to use the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#emailForm").submit(function() {
            console.log("Submit prevented.");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: "send.php",     
                data: {
                    email: $("#email").val()
                },
            success: function(data) {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    window.location = obj.url;
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

while I changed send.php to the following:

```
<?php
    $xml = file_get_contents('xml.xml');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://the.website/xxx/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

    $sXML = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $oXML = simplexml_load_string($sXML);
    $url = (string) $oXML->RETURNEDURL;

    if (isset($_POST["email"]))
    {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    } else {
        $email = null;
    }

    session_start();
    setcookie("email", $email);
    $arr = array("url"=>$url);
    echo(json_encode($arr));
?>
```

It now works like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Add the data-ajax="false" attribute to your form and it should work as intended in your first version.
Check http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/forms/forms-sample.html for details.